# Xcode 4.6 or greater is required to run iOS commands when running: meteor run ios

Tags: ios, xcode, meteor

I start to run the meteor project on ios device. usin the following command:

```
sudo meteor run ios
```

However it reports me the following error :

`Xcode 4.6 or greater is required to run iOS commands.`

I have got my Xcode installed wiht version 6.3.1 together with the command line tools on OSX version 10.10.2

The full log is :

```
    sudo meteor run ios --verbose
Password:
% Parsing the --port option
% Will compile mobile builds                  
Local package version is up-to-date: accounts-base@1.2.0
Local package version is up-to-date: accounts-password@1.1.1
Local package version is up-to-date: aldeed:autoform@4.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: aldeed:collection2@2.3.3
Local package version is up-to-date: aldeed:simple-schema@1.3.3
Local package version is up-to-date: anti:fake@0.4.1
Local package version is up-to-date: autoupdate@1.2.1
Local package version is up-to-date: base64@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: bengott:avatar@0.7.6
Local package version is up-to-date: binary-heap@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: blaze@2.1.2
Local package version is up-to-date: blaze-tools@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: boilerplate-generator@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: callback-hook@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: check@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: coffeescript@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: dburles:collection-helpers@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: deps@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: dispatch:kernel@0.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date:          
dispatch:request-animation-frame@0.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: ejson@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: email@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: fastclick@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: fourseven:scss@2.1.1
Local package version is up-to-date: geojson-utils@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: ground:db@0.3.9
Local package version is up-to-date: ground:dictionary@0.2.0
Local package version is up-to-date: ground:localstorage@0.1.8
Local package version is up-to-date: ground:minimax@1.1.2
Local package version is up-to-date: ground:servertime@0.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: ground:store@0.1.1
Local package version is up-to-date: ground:util@0.1.13
Local package version is up-to-date: html-tools@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: htmljs@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: http@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: id-map@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:controller@1.0.8
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:core@1.0.8
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:dynamic-template@1.0.8
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:layout@1.0.8
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:location@1.0.9
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:middleware-stack@1.0.9
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:router@1.0.9
Local package version is up-to-date: iron:url@1.0.9
Local package version is up-to-date: jparker:crypto-core@0.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: jparker:crypto-md5@0.1.1
Local package version is up-to-date: jparker:gravatar@0.3.1
Local package version is up-to-date: jquery@1.11.3_2
Local package version is up-to-date: json@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: launch-screen@1.0.2
Local package version is up-to-date: less@1.0.14
Local package version is up-to-date: livedata@1.0.13
Local package version is up-to-date: localstorage@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: logging@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: matb33:collection-hooks@0.7.13
Local package version is up-to-date: mdg:camera@1.1.4
Local package version is up-to-date: meteor@1.1.6
Local package version is up-to-date: meteor-platform@1.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: meteorhacks:async@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: meteorhacks:npm@1.3.0
Local package version is up-to-date: meteoric:autoform-ionic@0.1.5
Local package version is up-to-date: meteoric:ionic@0.1.17
Local package version is up-to-date: meteoric:ionic-sass@0.1.9
Local package version is up-to-date: meteoric:ionicons-sass@0.1.6
Local package version is up-to-date: minifiers@1.1.5
Local package version is up-to-date: minimongo@1.0.8
Local package version is up-to-date: mobile-status-bar@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: momentjs:moment@2.10.3
Local package version is up-to-date: mongo@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: mrt:jquery-jcrop@0.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: mrt:nprogress@0.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: mrt:underscore-string-latest@2.3.3
Local package version is up-to-date: npm-bcrypt@0.7.8_2
Local package version is up-to-date: observe-sequence@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: ordered-dict@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: raix:eventemitter@0.1.2
Local package version is up-to-date: raix:eventstate@0.0.2
Local package version is up-to-date: raix:onetimeout@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: raix:push@2.6.10
Local package version is up-to-date: raix:stubfence@1.0.1
Local package version is up-to-date: random@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: reactive-dict@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: reactive-var@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: reload@1.1.3
Local package version is up-to-date: retry@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: reywood:publish-composite@1.3.6
Local package version is up-to-date: routepolicy@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: service-configuration@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: session@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: settinghead:auto-nprogress@1.0.0
Local package version is up-to-date: sha@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: spacebars@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: spacebars-compiler@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: srp@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: stylus@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: templating@1.1.1
Local package version is up-to-date: tracker@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: ui@1.0.6 
Local package version is up-to-date: underscore@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date:          
underscorestring:underscore.string@3.0.3_1
Local package version is up-to-date: url@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: webapp@1.2.0
Local package version is up-to-date: webapp-hashing@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: zimme:iron-router-active@1.0.4
% Running build for platforms: [ 'ios' ]      
Running command  /usr/bin/xcrun cc --version  
% Building the cordova build project          
% Bundling the web.cordova program of the app 
% Ensuring the cordova build project          
% Reading the mobile control file             
% Running the mobile control file             
% Copying resources for mobile apps           
% Writing new config.xml                      
% Ensuring that platforms in cordova build project are in sync
Using (built-in) Android SDK at               
/Users/Yongfeng/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk
% Running synchronously:  /Users/Yongfeng/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh [ 'platform', 'list' ]
% The output of `cordova platforms list`: Installed platforms: 
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, android, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, ios

% The platform is not in the Cordova project: android
Found com.intel.kext.intelhaxm:  undefined    
% The platform is not in the Cordova project: ios
Running command  /usr/bin/xcrun cc --version  
% Adding a platform ios                       
Using (built-in) Android SDK at               
/Users/Yongfeng/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk
% Running synchronously:  /Users/Yongfeng/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh [ 'platform', 'add', 'ios' ]
Xcode 4.6 or greater is required to run iOS commands.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my problem solved by refering [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/UBmkwFKiCi4)

> the 'head' command which Cordova uses to determine the Xcode version is been replace by the 'head' in perl from the XAMPP. You can type 'which head' to see the scripts calls it. In my case I had to comment out the "export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH" in my bash_profile

So just removing the XAMPP bin folder from PATH solved my problem.

cheers!